# Make GNU make use a different compiler

Tags: c++, c, makefile

How can I make GNU Make use a different compiler without manually editing the makefile?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
make CC=my_compiler
```

This is assuming whoever wrote the Makefile used the variable CC.

Comment: Commonly used variables are `CC`, `GCC`, `CCX`, etc... but, as stated, one has to read the `Makefile` to see what variable(s) are used (and also if it's C++ or C). Just came across this answer while using a Makefile that has a check if you're using `GCC` (eg, `make GCC=gcc-6`) and prints an error message asking to instead use `HOST_COMPILER` (e.g., `make HOST_COMPILER=g++-6` vs my default of `g++` , which is newer v7) (fyi it's the Nvidia CUDA samples).

Comment: this is a terrible answer, it does not cover what is supposed to go in "my compiler"

Answer (score 29):

You can set the environment variables `CC` and `CXX`, which are used for compiling C and C++ files respectively. By default they use the values `cc` and `g++`

Comment: If the makefile was written to use CC and CCX

Comment: Setting environment doesn't override explicit values in a makefile unless you use '-e' to tell make to let it do so.  It does override defaults, though - and most likely the defaults are used.

Answer (score 22):

If the makefile is written like most makefiles, then it uses `$(CC)` when it wishes to invoke the C compiler. That's what the built-in rules do, anyway. If you specify a different value for that variable, then Make will use that instead. You can provide a new value on the command line:

```
make CC=/usr/bin/special-cc
```

You can also specify that when you run `configure`:

```
./configure CC=/usr/bin/special-cc
```

The configuration script will incorporate the new `CC` value into the makefile that it generates, so you don't need to *manually* edit it, and you can just run `make` by itself thereafter (instead of giving the custom `CC` value on the command line every time).

Answer (score 11):

Many makefiles use 'CC' to define the compiler.  If yours does, you can [override that variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding) with

```
make CC='/usr/bin/gcc'
```

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 1):

Use variables for the compiler program name.
Either pass the new definition to the `make` utility or set them in the environment before building.

See [Using Variables in Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference)

Answer (score 0):

Makefile:

```
#!MAKE

suf=$(suffix $(src))
ifeq ($(suf), .c)
cc=gcc
else
ifeq ($(suf), .cpp)
cc=g++
endif
endif

all:
    $(cc) $(src) -o $(src:$(suf)=.exe)

clean:
    rm *.exe

.PHONY: all clean
```

Terminal:

```
$ make src=main.c
```