# Make error: I want the make file to use gcc compiler flags but originally it uses intel

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, linker, cc, icc

I also tried `make -icpc="CXX"`
`make -icc="cc"` gives the error.

> make: invalid option -- 'c'
>       make: invalid option -- 'c'
>       make: invalid option -- '='
>       make: invalid option -- 'c'
>       make: invalid option -- 'c'

Currently Loaded Module files:

> gcc
>      make
>      python/2.7.11
>      openmpi/1.10.1-gnu
>      hdf5/1.8.10-intel
>      boost/1.60.0-gnu5
>      mkl/2013.5.192
>      mpich/3.1.2-gnu

Comment: Can you add more explanations ? At least post (part of) your `Makefile`.

Comment: -include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include oed/subdir.mk
-include objects/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
..
..                                                                                                                                                  I added parts of the makefile. Thx!

Comment: What compiler flag are you trying to pass to the compiler? Are you trying to use a Make variable?

Comment: Nobody can respond to your questions this way! Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @beta: I want it to use cc and CXX instead of icpc and icc

Comment: yes, as a make variable.

Comment: You want *what* to use them? Are those variable names, or variable values? I think you are laboring under a deep misunderstanding of how makefiles work. Could you post your makefile, or at least the rule that would use these... things?

Comment: Did you already see that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969244/4872413 ?